# Trigger syntax error with phpadmin mysql

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I need the right syntax for MySQL trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `parent_comm`    
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `employee` FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
       SET NEW.`parent_com`=(NEW.`com_amt`*10/100)
       WHERE `id` = NEW.`parent_id`
  END;
```

ERROR:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `id` = NEW.`parent_id`
>   END' at line 5

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) before aksing here

Comment: The where in the set statement makes no sense, every statement must be terminated, you don't appear to be setting delimiters (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html), since there is only 1 statement you don't need begin and end statements.